# sorting the stacking order according to the z position as3

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d, indexing, position

I'm attempting to set the stacking order (z **index**) of movieclips to be chosen according to the z **position** of each mc.

I have hundreds of mcs each given a x y z position from external data that i am retrieving.
everything is positioned well but the stacking order - which by default is set as the order of the appearance of each mc in my loop.

One uncomfortable option that i dont really wish to pursue is sorting the data according to the z positions before attaching the mcs in a loop.

Is there a quicker, more elegant way to do this?

thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sortOn`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sortOn%28%29) to sort an array of your MovieClips by their `z` property, and then add them all to your container using a loop like you described. This is the probably the cleanest and most elegant way to do this.

Assuming you have an array `list` with your MovieClips in it:

```
// Sort the list and add the children.
list.sortOn("z", Array.NUMERIC);
for each(var i:DisplayObject in list)
{
    addChild(i);
}
```

If the order is wrong, just add `list.reverse()` before the for loop.

With 1000 Sprites having a randomly generated `z` value between 0 and 1000, this process takes 3ms on my machine, which is exceptional.

Answer (score 0):

If your items are all children of a common parent, you could do it this way:

```
function goSort(container:DisplayObjectContainer):void {
    var list:Vector.<DisplayObject> = new Vector.<DisplayObject>();
    var i:int = container.numChildren;
    while(i--){
        list.push(container.getChildAt(i));
    }

    list.sort(sortZ);

    for(var i:int=0;i<list.length;i++){
        container.addChild(list[i]);
    }
}

function sortZ(a:DisplayObject, b:DisplayObject):Number {
    return a.z - b.z;
}
```

Then call:

```
goSort(yourContainer);
```